# Linking issues with wxWidget sample on Ubuntu 12.04 (amd64)

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, wxwidgets

I have a problem linking the wxWidget sample application (http://www.wxwidgets.org/docs/tutorials/hello.htm) with is stored in main.cpp. I try to compile and link it using:

```
g++ `wx-config --cxxflags --libs` main.cpp
```

The output I get is the following:

```
/tmp/ccFHWUaX.o: In function `wxCreateApp()':
main.cpp:(.text+0x31): undefined reference to `wxAppConsole::CheckBuildOptions(char const*, char const*)'
/tmp/ccFHWUaX.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x91): undefined reference to `wxEntry(int&, char**)'
/tmp/ccFHWUaX.o: In function `MyFrame::MyFrame(wxString const&, wxPoint const&, wxSize const&)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x1d2): undefined reference to `wxFrameNameStr'
main.cpp:(.text+0x267): undefined reference to `wxEmptyString'
main.cpp:(.text+0x2ea): undefined reference to `wxEmptyString'
main.cpp:(.text+0x366): undefined reference to `wxMenuBar::wxMenuBar()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x3d1): undefined reference to `wxFrameBase::SetMenuBar(wxMenuBar*)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x3da): undefined reference to `wxStatusLineNameStr'
main.cpp:(.text+0x407): undefined reference to `wxFrame::CreateStatusBar(int, long, int, wxString const&)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x44f): undefined reference to `wxFrameBase::SetStatusText(wxString const&, int)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x533): undefined reference to `wxFrame::~wxFrame()'
(and many lines more...)
```

WxWidgets-2.8 is installed using the ubuntu repository and its libs are located in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu. I also tried to build specifying the library path with:

```
-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

but, this does not change the output. I was blaming multiarch for my problem, but actually only as I don't know how it works exactly.

Can someone tell me how to build the sample correctly?

Thank you
Michael

Comment: Have you tried putting the `wx-config --libs` *after* your source file in the command line?

Comment: I would definitely run `wx-config --cxxflags --libs` from a command prompt and verify that it includes the "-L" (library search path) and "-l" (library file) entries you expect.  It's possible wx-config isn't configured correctly.  IMHO..

Comment: That is strange... Why do I have to put them behind the source file? I am using eclipse and there the linker flags are placed before the inputs by default. Changing the order fixed the issue, awesome thank you. Btw: output from wx-config is setting -L and -l entries correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using static linking, the libraries must always come *after* the object files using the symbols from them, otherwise they're simply ignored by the linker as they're not needed at the moment when it first sees them. So [us2012](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1865077/us2012) is correct, you need to put `wx-config` part after your source file.

You could also use shared wxWidgets libraries, then the order wouldn't matter. But it's still a good habit to use the right order, which works for both static and shared libraries, anyhow.

Comment: If that is true, then I did not get the concept of static linking under linux. 
In windows, you have a aLibrary.dll and aLibrary.lib file. When you link against aLibrary, you always link statically against aLibrary.lib. aLibrary.lib is generated in such a way that it internally calls LoadLibrary("aLibrary.dll") and GetProcAddress("someFunc") to create a function table. So there is no real dynamic linking. Am I right?

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with Windows import libraries (which are quite different from static libraries). I'm really only speaking about the linker algorithm for determining the libraries to use, it has absolutely no effect on the generated executable.

Comment: I did not ever realize there is an order in linking. And how I read the manpage the parameters are fully determined by flags and no order happens when not using the same flag several times. 

The g++ manpage says:

"You can mix options and other arguments. For the most part, the
 order you use doesn't matter. Order does matter when you use 
 several options of the same kind; for example, if you specify -L 
 more than once, the directories are searched in the order 
 specified. Also, the placement of the -l option is significant."
Could you please elaborate that?

Comment: You can find more detailed explanations with an easy web search but the long and short of it is already in my answer: with traditional Unix linkers, including GNU ld, when linking statically, the libraries must come after the object files (and other libraries) referencing symbols from them.